# Loadbalance based on incoming port specified in Kubernetes (On premise)

Tags: kubernetes, service, port

Is there a way to load balance based on the incoming port specified in the URL while using kubernetes.
For ex: xyz.com:10021 should direct to a specific service port and xyz.com:10025 should direct to another service port.

Similar to path based mapping in ingress , is it possible to do it based on the port ??

Comment: Can you use nodeport service? Basically you would be creating two separate NodePort services and whenever request comes on either of the service it would reach the underlying pod. However the port range for nodePort service is different from what you are asking.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#:~:text=Type%20NodePort,the%20allocated%20port%20in%20its%20.

Comment: The nodeport service anyhow needs to be accessed by external URL right  ??
Here the URL will be specified along with port externally and based on the port specified the services needs to be reached

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. Do you want to use k8s as LB? Can you provide a bit more details about your build?

Comment: @Sach Since you are in on premise, you can use a LBs to point to the nodeport service. Anyways I found the below link, see if it is helpful.
https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/is-possible-to-configure-ingress-via-port-base-routing/7167

Comment: Thanks Naveen. 
I managed to have it done using https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

The solution is the same as mentioned in the link you shared.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to have it done using https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/